# Postgres password hash crack

Tags: postgresql

I installed the lastest version of PostgreSQL (13.2) to understand it better and I used the command `SELECT usename, passwd from pg_shadow;` to extract the hash with the default username `postgres` but I could not find any documantation of how to crack the password hash using john or hashcat so how can I do that ?
the hash example which is **1234**

```
SCRAM-SHA-256$4096:bPlu66YYvUgvDwY31jQZTA==$ZbSxNzZQqdtLi+fcj15pg7ywEg5mO3xNOVfZJ+/2n0Q=:9ll3Le0+81qTnFwonM4ROCzeTjCRizYdm3ZO5yu/wcE=
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use a crack method that is designed for `SCRAM-SHA-256`. If jtr or hashcat do not have this (and it looks like they [don't](https://github.com/hashcat/hashcat/issues/2551) at this point in time), then you cannot use those tools.

Hashcat is [working on this](https://github.com/hashcat/hashcat/issues/2551#issuecomment-703217168) for `-m 24200`. You might be able to find a dev version that includes this.